# Software developer internship without a degree

Tags: software-industry, internship

I would like to work for a software company during the holidays. I am just 17 and I do not have a computer science or related degree. However, I do feel pretty confident that I can add value to a company. Do you think I have a chance? What should I do to increase my chances of getting a job?

Comment: What would be a good way to demonstrate my abilities?

Comment: And what are you Iooking for in a someone from an internship?

Comment: Do you think I should make a portfolio with my github, stackoverflow, projects and courses I did and then put it on a personal website that I could link?

Comment: Being a competent programmer isn't all that is required for a software job. Have you considered working as a requirements/business analyst's assistant on a software team? This would gain you a lot experience in the software development process. It would also increase your long term hireability more than fixing bugs or code reviewing.

Comment: @Kys I think a highschool student has a much better shot at getting an internship coding than doing business analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Build relationships with people that work at software companies that may accept bringing you on temporarily to try you out.
2. Consider what terms are you expecting from the company as they would likely want someone that already has some skills rather than the person that has to spend a week getting some basic skills to contribute to a project.
3. Understand that this kind of set-up may work better at start-ups where there isn't as much paperwork and HR stuff as big companies would have for my last point here. If you are going through a school sponsored internship then the established companies may work and while you don't have the degree, you would be on your way to this as co-operative education programs exist as a way this would work. However, to get a job directly without the assistance of a school at such a company may be harder though some companies may run "Code Camps" or other similar projects. [Google's Summer of Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code) being an example for university students.

Comment: Upvoted, however point 3 may not be accurate - many large companies have well established apprenticeship/internship/graduate programmes.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, thanks for the catch. I elaborated on that point as I can question if someone in high school could get a job at the big company directly without going through a school of some form as the OP notes they are in high school at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a professional web developer and have no formal training; it's just something that I did as a hobby for a significant chunk of my life, then landed a junior position in my late 20s when I decided to pursue it as a career. All I had to show was a few little projects that I did in my free time, and a couple of interesting (admittedly poorly written!) web applications that I had made for my previous employer to help streamline some of their processes.

Building up a small portfolio of two or three projects that showcase your skills - even if they're not fully finished - is a good way to impress someone in a job interview, despite your CV/Resume not including any relevant educational experience.

I've since been in a position where I've been responsible for hiring developers, and I have hired applicants like you that are eager to learn and work hard so long as they've been able to show potential. You'd be surprised how many computer science graduates fail a simple practical interview test like 'FizzBuzz'!

Good luck!

Comment: Well, I allready coded a Fizbuzz in python with only 66 characters. :)

Comment: Just a question if you don't mind me asking - what's about your salary having done that path?

Comment: @Joe C: I took a significant pay cut when I first got into web development (about 20%) because I went into a junior role. I was back up to my original salary after about a year, and have since moved to different companies a few times with significant increases in pay each time I did. I now make just as much as my colleagues that are a similar age to me, despite not being a developer for as long.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to increase my chances of getting a job?

The way which has the best chance at your age, qualifications, and experience is by personal referral.

Everything else is a long shot at best unless you can get a position through your school if you're at one.

Other IT related positions would probably be more suitable and easier to attain, rather than developer. Working in a retail for example...

The only way I'd hire you as a developer is as a favour to a friend or client (no offence). But I might hire you as an assistant or other very junior position and give you a chance to prove yourself and earn experience.

Answer (score 0):

- Learn as much as you can about software development (as opposed to just 'coding') : developing and maintaining test suites, project management, continuous integration, common coding style standards, and so on.
- Develop a professional (but interesting!)-looking online portfolio showcasing your skills.
- Try to get your CV through to (or have a talk with) people who might be impressed by your portfolio (technical people with a say in hiring) rather than people who might just filter you out based on qualifications (more straightforward HR people?).
- Apply to companies whose business you feel you understand, and learn as much as you can about each company before applying, tailoring your application accordingly.